# Lucene: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, hibernate, build, constructor, lucene

I am using Lucene 3.4.0, hibernate (hibernate-all.jar), ANT and TestNG to run some test...
Most of all works right now, but since I have implemented my lucene part nothing seems to work when I use ant command... I'm kind of lost here.

Because everything works perfectly locally. I can run my test, compile, etc. As soons as, I try to build with ant, I get this error "cannot find symbol" for contructor StandartAnalyzer(version.), etc...

But like I said, everything works on eclipse... At first, I had an method not found error, but fixed it because hibernate is not compatible with the latest version of lucene. So I upgraded hibernate... but now, I get this.

Thank you. If you need more information plz ask.

```
    $ ant explode
Buildfile: c:\DuplicateBugFinder\dbf\build.xml

init:

groovy.compile:

groovy.copy:

compile:
    [javac] c:\DuplicateBugFinder\dbf\build.xml:156: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=l
st; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 27 source files to c:\DuplicateBugFinder\dbf\exploded-archives\dbf.ear\dbf_jar
    [javac] c:\DuplicateBugFinder\dbf\src\hot\com\rim\sts\dbf\business\service\classification\LuceneClassificationAlgorithm.java:
6: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : constructor StandardAnalyzer(org.apache.lucene.util.Version)
    [javac] location: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer
    [javac]     Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34);
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] c:\DuplicateBugFinder\dbf\src\hot\com\rim\sts\dbf\business\service\classification\LuceneClassificationAlgorithm.java:
2: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : constructor QueryParser(org.apache.lucene.util.Version,java.lang.String,org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer

    [javac] location: class org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser
    [javac]             new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_34, "title", analyzer)
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] c:\DuplicateBugFinder\dbf\src\hot\com\rim\sts\dbf\business\service\classification\LuceneClassificationAlgorithm.java:
9: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : constructor IndexSearcher(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory,boolean)
    [javac] location: class org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher
    [javac]       searcher = new IndexSearcher(index, true);
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] c:\DuplicateBugFinder\dbf\src\hot\com\rim\sts\dbf\business\service\classification\LuceneClassificationAlgorithm.java:
00: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector)
    [javac] location: class org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher
    [javac]       searcher.search(q, collector);
    [javac]               ^
    [javac] 4 errors

BUILD FAILED
c:\DuplicateBugFinder\dbf\build.xml:156: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fixed it. I needed to add the jar file in  my lib/test (I'm using seam framework). In eclipse, everything was working because I was pointing to the jar in my run configurations for TestNG. When I was running the command "ant test" no jar was found...

So thanks to everyone.

Plus, for those of you who wants to make use of lucene and seam make sure too have no version incompatibilty. I had this problem for a long time. Finally, I found out that I had to use an older version of lucene (2.4.1) to work with seam 2.2. I didn't check yet for lucene 3.4 and seam 3...

Answer (score 1):

It's probablly a difference in the classpathes used by Eclipse and by Ant respectively. Check what jars are you exactly using inside Eclipse (what libraries are added to the project) and then what jars you use in your declared Ant classpath when you build with that. Also check that you're using the same JDK in Eclipse and Ant. If either of the two differ, change Ant ones to be like Eclipse (since that's the environment that does work)

Answer (score 1):

Check the ant classpath for multiple versions of Lucene library. Do `ant -diagnostics` to check the ant environment.